# Android Proguard Mongodb

Tags: android, mongodb, proguard, bson

Proguard complains when I try to export my Android project. Here are the errors I am getting.

```
[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXConnector

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXConnector

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.JMException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXConnector

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.remote.JMXConnector

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServerConnection

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.tools.ConnectionPoolStat: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: com.mongodb.util.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: org.bson.types.ObjectId: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: org.bson.types.ObjectId: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: org.bson.types.ObjectId: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: org.bson.types.ObjectId: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean

[2012-12-17 16:52:46]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] Warning: there were 75 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

[2012-12-17 16:52:46]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)

[2012-12-17 16:52:46] at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

What are the necessary Proguard instructions to resolve these errors? Thanks.

Comment: Well, they are kind of right in front of you: `[2012-12-17 16:52:46]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').`. You need to tell Proguard about the external jars the project is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caused by Chartboost.

```
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**

-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class java.lang.management.** { *; }
```